# Node.JS - How to access Values of Dictionary within an Array of a Key in a Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, dictionary

I'm new in Node.JS and I'm able to parse the JSON data and do a console log to print out name and badges.

```
var details = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(details.name, details.badges.length);
```

But I don't know how I can get the data inside the arrays of the bagdes such as id, name, url.

I tried

```
console.log(details.badges.length.id);
```

But nothing shows up. How can I access that? Thank you.

```
{
"name": "Andrew Chalkley",
"badges": [
    {
      "id": 49,
      "name": "Newbie",
      "url": "http:\/\/teamtreehouse.com\/chalkers",
      "icon_url": "https:\/\/achievement-images.teamtreehouse.com\/Generic_Newbie.png",
      "earned_date": "2012-07-23T19:59:34.000Z",
      "courses": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "name": "Introduction",
      "url": "http:\/\/teamtreehouse.com\/library\/html\/introduction",
      "icon_url": "https:\/\/achievement-images.teamtreehouse.com\/HTML_Basics.png",
      "earned_date": "2012-07-23T21:57:24.000Z",
      "courses": [
        {
          "title": "HTML",
          "url": "http:\/\/teamtreehouse.com\/library\/html",
          "badge_count": 1
        },
        {
          "title": "Introduction",
          "url": "http:\/\/teamtreehouse.com\/library\/html\/introduction",
          "badge_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an array, so you need the index, for example: `details.badges[0].id`

This will return the first (index 0) element id.

`.length` only returns the length of the array, so it will not be useful to get the data in it.