# How to access values of dictionary of array of dictionary of array using node js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, dictionary, for-loop, jsonresult

I have some monotonous Json response in which I am trying access element of dictionary of array of dictionary of array using node.js but hard luck and unable to do so. I have tried accessing this stackoverflow solution `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448517/node-js-how-to-access-values-of-dictionary-within-an-array-of-a-key-in-a-dicti` but in my case this is not working appropriately. My Json response is :

```
{
  "client": [
    {

      "code": [
        {
          "id": "001",
          "code": "100",
          "type": "New"
        },
        {
          "id": "002",
          "code": "200",
          "type": "Old"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From this response I want to get value of each "id", "code" and "Type". Any valuable answer would be appreciated. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

If your json was assigned to the variable x

```
 x = {
   "client": [
     {

       "code": [
         {
           "id": "001",
           "code": "100",
           "type": "New"
         },
         {
           "id": "002",
           "code": "200",
           "type": "Old"
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 }

console.log(x["client"][0]["code"][0]["id"])
```

(I'll leave iterating through the arrays as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: I just tried your solution but ended up with error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: copy and paste the code block into a node.js terminal window. it should print out 001